# Check the struct free or not after free it

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct _person
{
    char name[64];
    char gender[2];
    struct _person * pNext;
    struct _person * pPartner;
} PERSON_T;

typedef struct
{
    PERSON_T * head;
    PERSON_T * tail;
    PERSON_T * current;
} LIST_T;
```

I have the struct and then i free like this

```
void freestruct(LIST_T *linkedList)
{
    linkedList->current = linkedList->head;
    if (linkedList != NULL) /* if list has been initialized  */
        {
        PERSON_T * pThisItem = linkedList->head;
        while (pThisItem != NULL)
            {
            PERSON_T * pNext = pThisItem->pNext;
            free(pThisItem);
            pThisItem = pNext;
            }
        free(linkedList);
        }
}
```

How i can check that its free or not beacuse i dont know the functionfree that i made it right or not.

sorry about my english

Thank you.

Comment: `linkedList != NULL` It is too late to of checking after using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether an address is free or not it is enough to check the address equals to NULL.

```
linkedList == NULL
```

since you are using free(linkedList) it should be okay.